# How to call a custom module from another python module in colab

Tags: python, import, module, google-colaboratory

I would like to how to call a custom module from another python module in colab. I am using the below code for invoking a custom function myfunc() in my custom module test.

```
    from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
    from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
    from google.colab import auth
    from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

    auth.authenticate_user()
    gauth = GoogleAuth()
    gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

    from test import myfunc
    myfunc()
```

Comment: I have a line for linking to the module using drive.createFile() which I have not shown above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab the file_id from it's shareable link (i.e. if you go into your drive, right-click, and click 'get shareable link', you'll get a url that looks like "drive.google.com/open?id=**126kITmfmEqI0XM0z...**") and place it in the following executable - should accomplish what you're trying to do.

```
drive.CreateFile({'id':'file_id'}).GetContentFile('test.py')

from test import myfunc
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, It worked. How do I ensure the changes in the module are reflected in my calling module. Do I need to restart the runtime every time I need to get the latest changes in the module.

Comment: As far as I'm aware ya you'll need to restart your runtime and rerun your notebook if you update 'test.py'